# Microsoft Graph WebHook: Subscription validation request timed out

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

This is the ruby code I'm using to create a subscription in microsoft graph:

```
subscribe_endpoint = URI("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions")
http = Net::HTTP.new(subscribe_endpoint.host, subscribe_endpoint.port)
http.use_ssl = true
tomorrow = Date.today + 1

subscribe_request = "{
  \"changeType\": \"created,updated\",
  \"notificationUrl\": \"https://my_url/api/v1/outlook/o365notification\",
  \"resource\": \"/users/#{params[:o365account_id]}/events?$filter=Extensions/any(f:f/id eq 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.OpenTypeExtension.meeteor_event')\",
  \"expirationDateTime\": #{(Time.now + 1.day).to_json},
  \"clientState\": \"SecretClientState\"
}"

subscribe_response = http.post(
    "/v1.0/subscriptions",
    subscribe_request,
    'Authorization' => "Bearer #{params[:o365account_access_token]}",
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
)
```

It worked great, but suddenly today I'm getting a `Subscription validation request timed out` response. Altough when I'm doing a POST to `https://my_url/api/v1/outlook/o365notification` it's just working fine.

Any ideas why it stopped working when nothing changed on my side?

Could it be that, because `my_url` points on my dev environment and is often offline, the domain got banned?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is probably some change on your notification server, either service or network configuration. It does not response to validation requests. I also tried POST request with HTTP instead of HTTPS to your server, it returned 200 but without validation token in response body.

Comment: But doing the POST on the same URL with Fiddler works (even outside from my network) all the time. And if my endpoint returns 200 without the validation token, then the error response from the subscription endpoint would be different than the timeout message I'm getting, it looks like the POST request isn't performed on the provided URL.

Comment: I sent an email to your Gmail. Let's follow up offline to avoid disclosing your server details.

Comment: If anybody is interested: after our offline follow up it turned out that it's a connection issue, after my endpoint was deployed on a cloud service it worked. For endpoints pointing to dev machines ngrok is suggested.