# Microsoft Graph : Subscription validation request timed out

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We have .net application to create a subscription in Microsoft Graph. We only can get it worked with Ngrok URL, but never get it worked with custom notification URL due to error - 'Subscription validation request time out'. I found below articles re this issue, but didn't see the detail of the solution. Can anyone please help? Much appreciate.

[Microsoft Graph WebHook: Subscription validation request timed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41621627/microsoft-graph-webhook-subscription-validation-request-timed-out/41627293#41627293)
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/6449

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVb52.png)

Comment: Thanks for reaching out to us , could you please provide the code snippet .which will help us know figure out the actually problem

Comment: For which resource you are trying to create subscription?

Comment: Hi Vicky, here is the code snippet

{
    "changeType": "created",
    "notificationUrl": "https://myurl/notification/listen",
    "resource": "me/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
    "expirationDateTime": "2022-07-28T11:23:45.9356913Z",
    "clientState": "secretClientValue",
    "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v1_2"
}

Answer (score 0):

thanks for reaching out to us ,

This indicates that Microsoft Graph did not receive a validation response within the expected time frame (about 10 seconds).

- Make sure that you are not paused in the debugger when the validation
  request is received. If you're using ngrok,
- make sure that you used    your project's HTTP port for the tunnel
  (not HTTPS).

ref doc - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnetcore-webhooks-sample/blob/main/TROUBLESHOOTING.md

[image]

Hope this helps , please let us know if you have any query.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks Vicky. We use HTTP port, not HTTPS.As I mentioned earlier, it works when using ngrok, but not work with our customized URL which is hosted on Azure VM.

The validation of our customized URL takes more than 11 seconds which failed the validation. We tried to figure out why caused the that, but no luck. Do you have any ideas how we can troubleshoot this?Thanks.

Comment: Everything looks good from graph end  , there might be network issue  , the best thing i can recommend you to debug from your end or you use fiddler. hope this help to find out the actual cause .thanks

Comment: Thanks Vicky, we did debug using fiddler with Microsoft support, but could not identify the root cause, hence I created this post here to ask for help.

Comment: I also found this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63708841/timeout-error-during-subscription-to-push-notifications. The url we used is a custom domain.